# How to check in julia if a vector of bool is all falses

Tags: julia

I just wander if there is some pre built-in `and()` function or something better than this one:

```
filter = [true,false,true,false]
length([i for i in filter if i]) > 0 # true

filter = [false,false,false]
length([i for i in filter if i]) > 0 # false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
julia> x = [true,false,true,false]
4-element Array{Bool,1}:
  true
 false
  true
 false

julia> all(x)
false
```

Sorry, you said 'all falses'. Then:

```
julia> all(!, x)
```

or

```
julia> any(x)
```

Comment: there is function `any`

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer to your question, but note that `filter` is an existing function, so you probably won't want to overwrite it.

```
julia> a = [true, false, true, false];
julia> filter(!, a)
 2-element Array{Bool,1}:
 false
 false
julia> filter(!!, a)
 2-element Array{Bool,1}:
 true
 true
```

Answer (score 1):

`sum()` is actually the fastest:

```
x = falses(1_000_000)

julia> @benchmark sum(x)
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  0 bytes
  allocs estimate:  0
  --------------
  minimum time:     2.834 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      2.905 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        3.079 μs (0.00% GC)
  maximum time:     12.648 μs (0.00% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     9

julia> @benchmark all(!, x)
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  0 bytes
  allocs estimate:  0
  --------------
  minimum time:     546.055 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      546.463 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        558.960 μs (0.00% GC)
  maximum time:     1.709 ms (0.00% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          8928
  evals/sample:     1

@benchmark any(x)
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  0 bytes
  allocs estimate:  0
  --------------
  minimum time:     5.728 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      5.752 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        6.044 μs (0.00% GC)
  maximum time:     28.300 μs (0.00% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     6
```